# How to convert one time stamp into the time zone of another timezone, without knowing the timezones

Tags: javascript

I've got 2 timestamps

**A:**

`2019-09-25 19:46:36`

and

**B:**

`2019-09-26 03:47:01`

Without knowing what the timezones are, I'm trying to figure out a way to have A be converted into the same timezone as B.

**Desired output:**

**A:**

`2019-09-25 03:46:36`

So far all of my code has been made in vanilla Javascript, so ideally I'd like to keep it like that rather than involve Moment, but if I have to then I can work it out.

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this, but I've only really just started using Javascript.

If I had the same time in both timezones, it would be easier, as I could just calculate the difference and then apply that to the other timestamp. But because one is always slightly further on than the other, I've run into this problem.

Comment: "*Without knowing what the timezones are, I'm trying to figure out a way to have A be converted into the same timezone as B.*" this is impossible. It's like saying "I have the equation `x + y` and without knowing what the values of either are, I want to find what the result is."

Comment: I thought about removing the 2x hour digits from A and replacing it with the 2x hour digits of B, but it doesn't account for if the 2 times cross over to a different hour (eg. A is 19:59:05 and B is 04:03:01. Is there a way to do this that takes into account the fact that it is time and is subject to change when it gets to a certain value?

Comment: It's simply impossible. The two values could be in neighbouring time zones (1 hour difference), they could be 9 time zones apart. There is no way to tell, as your timestamps show different times.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript `Date` objects don't have a timezone, they're just a Unix timestamp. `Date` has a `getTimezoneOffset()` method, but this always returns the timezone offset of the computer or browser, and can not be changed.

EDIT:

If you know that the first timestamp is within the same hour as the 2nd one, it's quite simple:

```
const first = new Date("2019-09-25 19:46:36")
const second = new Date("2019-09-26 03:47:01")
first.setHours(second.getHours))
```

Comment: It's from a log, so there are lots of lines and each line has a timestamp. All of the lines at the top are from one timezone (it can vary and there is nothing to indicate the zone) and when it gets to a line that begins with START: it switches to a different time zone (normally UK but it can also vary). In case it's relevant: the 2 lines with the different timestamps will always only be a minute or two different from each other

Comment: To convert a timestamp into the correct time zone, you have to know what timezone it is in. If the timezone can vary, it's usually specified in the log, e.g. `[08/Oct/2019:18:00:55 +0200]`. If not, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Is there not a more manual way to do this? If the times were always within the same hour, so they never crossed over to a different hour, this would be easy, as I could just change the hour digits from A to be the same as B, and keep the minutes the same. But I would need to account for the hour changing between A and B occurring, although it's rare